# Gradle Multi-project test dependencies no longer working in Eclipse for Gradle 6.7

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

Let's say I have 2 Gradle projects called "project-base" and "project-extension".
I want to be able to see the classes defined in the src/tests/java of "project-base" inside the src/tests/java of "project-extension", to be able to use common code between the test of the projects.
In order to do that, I put this in "project-extension":

```
dependencies { testImplementation project(path: ':project-base', configuration: 'testArtifacts')
```

This used to work until Gradle 6.6.1. But now I tried to switch to Gradle 6.7 and it does not work in Eclipse. Eclipse will be able to navigate to the classes in "project-base" but will still show them in red and refuse to compile, saying that it cannot resolve the dependencies.
Note that this still works file in IntelliJIdea, even for Gradle 6.7, which makes me believe that it has to do with Buildship (Gradle plugin of Eclipse) not supporting this feature for Gradle 6.7 correctly.

Is there a way to still make this work for Gradle 6.7 in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be related to Eclipse and Buildship issues:

- https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12354
- https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/1009
- https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/14932

Adding this code to `build.gradle` solved problem.

```
plugins {
  id 'eclipse'
}

eclipse.classpath.file.whenMerged {
  entries.findAll { it instanceof org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.ProjectDependency }
    .each { it.entryAttributes['without_test_code'] = 'false' }
}
```